# SKVideoNode Not Working on Iphone 5 for 360 degree video

Tags: swift, 360-degrees, skvideonode, sceneview

I am working on 360 degree video player. I have done this throw SKVideoNode. it works fine on all other devices but it's not working on iphone 5. and it's showing black screen while playing video but we can hear audio. So please suggests me how i resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.